# PHP Imagick: saving a composition keeping vector images

Tags: php, vector-graphics, imagick

I have a script that take raster images (jpg) and vector (svg), compose it (scale, position, rotation, etc.) and then I need to save the final output as a PDF.

The problem is that using imagick, all the vector images get rasterized..

Is possible to create a pdf keeping the svg graphics as vector?